# Writing a Tokenized string into a text file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to save a tokenized string into a .txt file...
Example, in `Read.txt` is:

`She sells, sea shells, by the sea shore.`

I got my program to tokenize it but i can't seem to save the tokenized string into `Write.txt`

In `Write.txt` I just get:

`She sells, sea shells, by the sea shore.`

Basically I want to save what I output into `Write.txt`

Any help would be appreciated :D

Here are my outputs:

```
She sells, sea shells, by the sea shore.

[Split by spaces.]

She 
 sells,
 sea shells,
 by
 the
 sea
 shore.

-----------------------------

[Split by commas.]

She sells
 sea shells
 by the sea shore.
```

And my current codes:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class readWriteTokenized{
public static void main( String[] args ){

    String readString;

    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("Read.txt"));

        readString = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("\n" + readString);

        br.close();


        StringTokenizer stnz = new StringTokenizer(readString);

        System.out.println("\n[Split by spaces.]\n");
        while( stnz .hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(stnz .nextToken());
        }


        StringTokenizer stnz2 = new StringTokenizer(readString, ".");

        System.out.println("\n-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n\n[Split by comma.]\n");
        while( stnz2.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.print(stnz2.nextToken());
        }


        File NewTextFile = new File("C:/TestJava/Write.txt");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(NewTextFile);
        fw.write(readString);
        fw.close();     
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Catch error!");
    }       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `write()` each token, append it with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. A sample code will be :

```
while( stnz2.hasMoreTokens()){
    fw.write(stnz2.nextToken()+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Or, you can [decorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) your [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) with a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and use its [println()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29) method for formatting.

Comment: Cool! It works! Time to mess around with it a little, thank you for the reply :D